# error: "Operation not permitted" setting key "fs.file-max" while installing Oracle XE 11g on Centos 5.7 + OpenVZ

Tags: oracle11g, centos5, openvz

I am having problem in installing oracle xe 11g on centos 5.7 hosted on OpenVz

The server didnt have any swap space , and the oracle installation was refusing because of the swap=0
now its has been resolved. I am having problem to set the following oracle specific kernel params

```
# rpm -ivh oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
error: "Operation not permitted" setting key "fs.file-max"
error: "Operation not permitted" setting key "net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies"
error: %pre(oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 255
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this kernel parameters yourself manually and them rerun the rpm install:-

`vi /etc/sysctl.conf` and add the following lines:-

```
fs.file-max = 6815744
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
```

Then run

```
sysctl -p
```

You can see the kernel parameter settings in the Install Guide in [Section 2.13](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#autoId5), although net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies seems to be an additional setting for CENTOS

Comment: finel-max does not get updated because of the virtual environment

Comment: You need to set this for the container in OpenVz via /etc/vz/conf/abc.conf where abc is your container

Comment: Sorry no such file or folder hierarchy under /ect

Comment: It is in OpenVz server environment not your CentOS container.  You have to set some parameters when the container in closed.  You should read up a bit about how to do that and try to answer this issue yourself so that you can complete the environemnt set up correctly before trying the rpm again.